# Proof of repeated applications of L'hopital rule at a point

Tags: real-analysis

**NOTES**: I will not be assuming that the domains here after are an interval. For $f'(x)$ to be defined all I require is that the usual limit exists and $x$ is an accumulation point of the domain (may or may not be an interior point). Also I'll just be concentrating on $f(x)=0$ as $x \to 0$ for simplicity sake.

For a concrete example take the identity function restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$, $0$ is an accumulation point and you can see the limit is well defined. This definition is in Tao's Analysis books, for example. So $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x+h)-(x)}{h}=1$. This holds because every $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is an accumulation point of $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

Some terminology:

One-time L'hopital: If $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x)=0$, and $f'(0)$ and $g'(0)\not = 0 $ exist then $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$.

Repeated L'hopital: If $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x)=0$, and $f^{(a)}(0)=g^{(a)}(0)=0$  for $0<a<n$, and $f^{(n)}(0)$ and $g^{(n)}(0) \not = 0$ exist then $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{g^{(n)}(0)}$.

I've only seen proofs of the repeated L'hopital rule when the domain  of the function is an interval around $0$, while it's easy to see that the one-time L'hopital holds even when $x$ is not an interior point and just an accumulation point. My question is, is the repeated L'hopital true even if $x$ is only an accumulation point and not an interior point? Preferably without using Taylor's Theorem as I've found the same problem there, I've only seen proofs of it only when $x$ is an interior point.

Comment: If $f'$ exists at $0$, then does not the domain of $f$ contain an interval containing $0$?

Comment: Yes I meant $f'(0)/g'(0)$ will change, my bad. Also if $f'(0)$ exists then it is not necessarily an interior point, see the note. For a concrete example take the identity function restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$, $0$ is an accumulation point and you can see the limit is well defined. This definition is in Tao's Analysis books, for example.

Comment: @311411 Ok, I've edited the post.

Comment: I am still a bit unsure what is the motivation for this investigation. The notion of "interior point" depends on the notion of open ball, and an open ball is a subset of some ambient space. So do the real numbers play any role at all here (in your concrete example)?

Comment: Yes because the derivative $f'(0)$ may be a real number but not a rational one, e.g. pi. The motivation is that it's a generalization of the usual repeated L'hopital on an interval, for really weird looking functions, or normal functions restricted to a weird domain. In my example above with $f(x)=x$ L'hopital rule applies but this does not follow from the usual rule, as there's no interval around 0 in the rationals; hence my motivation is to check if this was luck or always happens.

Comment: If you replace "interval" with "neighborhood", you can use exactly the same proof for the special case, requiring the functions to be continuously differentiable. Just let your neighborhood be an interval intersected with the domain of your functions. I think the general version is not possible, since it relies on Mean Value theorem, which non-interval sets will often fail to satisfy

Comment: In repeated LHopital, you mean $f^{(a)}(0)$ etc ?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, my bad I will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without proper definitions it is hard to prove or disprove any statement.  So let us try to define the derivative of $f:S \to {\Bbb R}$ defined on the dense set $S\in[0,1]$. Let us say that the derivative at $x\in S$ is given by:
$$   f'(x)=\lim_{y\to x, y\in S} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x},$$
provided the limit exists. If is does for every $x\in S$ then we have obtained a function $f':S \to {\Bbb R}$ and can repeat the process to produce $f'':S\to {\Bbb R}$ etc... We do not try to extend $f'$ to a larger subset.

With this definition, your claim does not work for $n\geq 2$. An example: Let $S={\Bbb Q}\cap [0,1]$, $\alpha_0=1$ and let $\alpha_k$ be any strictly decreasing sequence of irrationals in $(0,1)$ going to zero and such that $\alpha_{k}/\alpha_{k+1}\to 1$ when $k\to +\infty$.
Define the intervals  $I_k=(\alpha_{k},\alpha_{k-1})_{k\in {\Bbb N}}$.
Then $\bigcup_{k\geq 1} I_k \supset S\cap (0,1)$.

For $x\in I_k\cap S$,
we set $f(x) = (\alpha_k+\alpha_{k-1})^2/4 $ and we let $f(0)=0$.
Then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)/x^2=1$. However,  every rational $x\in (0,1)\cap S$ is in the interior of some interval $I_k$ so $f$ is locally constant at $x$ and $f'(x)=0$ with our definition. Letting $x\to 0$ we also get $f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0^+,x\in S}  f(x)/x=0$. Our derivative is thus identically 0 on $S$ and we also deduce that $f''(x)=0$ for every $x\in S$. But then:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+,x\in S}  f(x)/x^2 =1 \neq 0 =\lim_{x\to 0^+, x\in S} f'(x)/2x= \lim_{x\to 0^+,x\in S} f''(x)/2$$

Comment: Thanks! Before marking this as the answer, there are two things that are still not clear to me. First, how do we know such $S$ exists? I think your intention is that the intervals get smaller the closer they are to $0$ but that is not clear from your construction, I think. Second, could you please elaborate why $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)/x^2=1$? It intuitively seems clear but it is not so clear to me.

Comment: I have simplified the construction.  When $\alpha_k/\alpha_{k+1}\to 1$ and $\alpha_{k+1}< x< \alpha_k$ then $f(x)\sim x^2$ as $x\to 0^+$ (and thus $k\to +\infty$).

Comment: Ohhh that's nice, thank you! this question had been bugging me for a while, do you have some sort of insight of *why* l'hopital fails?

Comment: I think it is related to the fact that l'Hôpital gives a link between increments and derivatives. To order 1 this only involves $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)/x$ and for this, restriction to a dense set $S$ makes no difference. But going to higher order you also need comparing $f'(x)-f'(0)$ to increments and this may fail i(as in the example) when the set $S$ is not connected (i.e. an interval).  If you look at proofs, e.g. on the wiki page on the subject, for $n\geq 2$ they typically involve the MVT, which again needs intervals (or at least a connected neighborhood of $0$) in order to work.